# View Not Expanding to Full List Line Width- SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swiftui

I have Views embedded in a list, one `View` per `List` item but for some reason, the `View` only takes up a small leading part of the list's row, rather than filling the full line. The embedded `View` is fully expanded in the preview of the `View` so I'm unsure why this is happening.

List `View`

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct AnnouncementsView: View{
    @Binding var announcements: [Announcement]
    @State var displayedMessage: String = ""
    @State var isDisplayingMessage: Bool = false
    
    static let sectionDateFormat: DateFormatter = {
        let formatter = DateFormatter()
        formatter.dateFormat = "dd/MM/YYYY"
        return formatter
    }()
    var body: some View{
        //NavigationView{
        VStack{
            List($announcements){$announcement in
                AnnouncementView(announcement: $announcement)
            }
            Spacer()
        }
    }
}
```

[image: list view preview]

List Item `View`

```swift
struct AnnouncementView: View{
    @Binding var announcement: Announcement
    @State private var sheetIsShowing: Bool = false
    static let sectionDateFormat: DateFormatter = {
        let formatter = DateFormatter()
        formatter.dateFormat = "dd/MM/YYYY"
        return formatter
    }()
    var body: some View{
        HStack{
            Button(action: {
                sheetIsShowing = true
            }){
                if (!announcement.read){
                    Image(systemName: "exclamationmark.circle.fill")
                        .foregroundColor(.red)
                }
                Text(announcement.message)
                    .lineLimit(1)
                    .truncationMode(.tail)
                    .foregroundColor(.black)
                Spacer()
                Text("\(announcement.timestamp, formatter: Self.sectionDateFormat)")
                    .disabled(true)
            }
        }
        .padding()
        .sheet(isPresented:$sheetIsShowing){
            NavigationView{
                DetailedAnnouncementView(announcement: $announcement)
                    .navigationTitle(Text("\(announcement.timestamp, formatter: Self.sectionDateFormat)"))
                    .toolbar{
                        ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarLeading){
                            Button(action: {
                                announcement.read = true
                                sheetIsShowing = false
                            }){
                                Text("Mark as Read")
                            }
                        }
                        ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarTrailing){
                            Button(action: {
                                sheetIsShowing = false
                                announcement.read = false
                            }){
                                Text("Mark as Unread")
                            }
                        }
                    }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image: list item view preview]

I'm probably missing something really basic but any help is much appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/a/63986460/12299030?

Comment: @Asperi Unfortunately not, thank you anyway.

Comment: Consider combining above with https://stackoverflow.com/a/60910124/12299030.

Comment: @Asperi Unfortunately this doesn't fix it either, I'm happy with the list style, that the list box is inset, its just that the View inside the list box refuses to go across the full line, and instead middle aligns to the leading edge over multiple lines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So it seems that SwiftUI renders `Button`'s content as if it was inside an `HStack` by default, in case no *Stack* was provided.

However, when using the `Button` inside a `List`, this default behaviour changes to defaulting as if it was a `VStack`. (Note that it only happens when used inside a `List`. When used inside `LazyVStack`, `ScrollView`, `ForEach`... the default `HStack` is maintained).

So, in order to make sure the `Button`'s content is always rendered horizontally, specify it by explicitly nesting its content inside an `HStack` instead of relying on `Button`'s *"default"* behaviour (as it does not seem to be consistent right now)

So, change:

```
Button(action: ...) {
    //content
}
```

To:

```
Button(action: ...) {
    HStack {
        //content
    }
}
```

Comment: Prefect solution. It was driving me crazy. Thank you.